# How can I capture Sublime 2 build output when it it sometimes on one line, sometimes on two lines

Tags: regex, build, sublimetext2

Title is a little long, but that's the best way to phrase the question.

I am using MivaScript as the programming language, so I am building all the tools to make it work in Sublime by hand. I have most everything working except the build system. My problem is that sometimes the compile errors appear on one line, sometimes on two lines.

If I am compiling a single file, the error line looks like this:

```
C:\internet\www\path\filename.mv:59: CE_191: Function "layout" called here with 0 parameters but with 1 parameters at line 27
```

But if the file includes other files, the output looks like this:

```
In file included from C:\internet\www\path\lib\file.mv at line 44
subdir/included_file.mv:42: CE_183: Expression is empty
```

It is split up on two lines; the first mentions the file I am compiling, the second is the path, filename, and line where the error exists.

What makes it worse is that single files have Windows style path including the drive. But if the error is in the included file, it uses a relative path in Linux format.

I am trying to use this for the file regex:

```
"file_regex": "^[a-z,A-Z]?:?\\?([^:]+):([0-9]+): [^:]+:.*$",
```

It is syntactically correct; tried searching in a doc I created with various error messages. But for some reason, it is not working in Sublime 2's build output search.

Any ideas? Is Sublime even capable of handling output on two lines?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I didn't try hard enough. Here is the final working solution:

```
^([a-z,A-Z]?:?[^:]+):([0-9]+): [^:]+: (.*)$
```

So this will capture the drive letter and colon if there, and then capture everything else including lead slashes. Sublime seems to figure it out from there.